# How to hide/unhide menubar of file manager PCmanFM with the Alt key?

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

In Windows Explore I have option to toggle menubar by using <kbd>ALT</kbd> key. Can I do it in PCmanFM? I'm willing to try coding stuff (for a bit).

Update information ::
I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS at the moment.

As for now, I would like to feature @guiverc answer because:

1. It seems like there isn't toggle feature for PCmanFM in 18.04
2. @guiverc answer provide quite lot information that could be useful for other questioner and future reference.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by toggle-menubar, but if I hit ALT+E I get the Edit menu opened so I can use the keyboard to pick an item. Likewise I can hit ALT+F for File, Alt+V for View etc...   *I'm running 19.04 so i tested this using `pcmanfm-qt` but I'd expect it to be the same*

Comment: thanks @DKBose (didn't know that).  A quick look shows ^M  (ctrl+M) on my `pcmanfm-qt` will toggle the menu bar being visible/invisible  (*but when invisible the alt+F/E I described before isn't working for me*).  It's possibly not an ideal solution, but it may be a little way there.

Comment: I think that Ctrl+M on pcmanfm-qt, checked in Lubuntu 18.10, is exactly what the poster wants!

Comment: Thanks @DKBose, you got me right. Unfortunately, I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS. Sorry for being lack of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I wasn't sure what you (original poster) was meant by toggle-menubar, so firstly though using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> I get the Edit menu opened so you can use the keyboard to pick an item. Likewise using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for File, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for View etc... *I tested this on 19.04's `pcmanfm-qt` as it was what I'm running at the time*

@DKBose however felt you were after the means to toggle the menu being visible (using Firefox as an example. A quick look in the shows *View->Toolbar->MenuVar* shows the 'menu' can be enabled/disabled (or visible/invisible) using a checkbox or ^M  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) on my `pcmanfm-qt` (DKBase confirmed it was the same in 18.10; I can check 18.04 later today using `pcmanfm` but I'd expect it to be).

A quick play whilst invisible showed that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> didn't pull up the Edit menu as I expected (likewise other Alt+menu-entries) until the toolbar was turned back on (or enabled) which may not be an ideal solution, but it's mostly there. (*my testing was limited; it was right before I went to bed...*)  It was not difficult though to just ^M first then use ^V to use the view menu option.

Comment: Yeah sorry. It doesn't work as I describe in `pcmanfm` under 18.04 LTS  (*no toggle feature as you discovered*). I'll return when/if I discover something else helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old by now but if anyone happens to come across this while searching for a solution: here is a quick patch to add the toggle feature to the GTK2 version of PCManFM (pressing Ctrl+M will bring back the menubar once hidden)
https://gist.github.com/M4he/3a8171a7f39d9ba9a0cf6bb387b08061
(written for PCManFM 1.3.1 on Debian Buster)

Comment: It worked for 1.3.2 that's available on Ubuntu 22.04, too. Thank you very much!